# Neodatis y duplicidades

Tags: java, base-de-datos, jframe, neodatis

Estoy trabajando con Neodatis interactuando a través de una interfaz gráfica Jframe. Cuando introduzco un jugador al estar la base de datos vacía, lo crea, justo despues de crear el país que yo le he dicho. Ahora bien, si introduzco otro nuevo jugador, pero con el mismo pais que el primero, vuelve a crearme un nuevo objeto pais, en vez de coger el que ya existe...

Código en la interfaz gráfica:

```
gestionLiga gestionLiga = new gestionLiga();

gestionLiga.altaJugador(txtNombre.getText(), txtDeporte.getText(), txtCiudad.getText(), Integer.parseInt(txtEdad.getText()), gestionLiga.sacarPais(txtPais.getText()));
```

Código de gestionLiga.sacarPais:

```
public Pais sacarPais(String pais)
    {
    odb = ODBFactory.open("EQUIPOS.test");
    IQuery query = new CriteriaQuery(Pais.class, Where.equal("nombre",pais));   
    Objects <Pais> listado = odb.getObjects(query);
    if(listado.size() == 0)
    {
        int contador;
        IQuery query2 = new CriteriaQuery(Pais.class);
        Objects <Pais> listado2 = odb.getObjects(query2);
        contador = listado2.size()+1;
        odb.close();
        return new Pais(contador, pais);
    }
    else
    {
        odb.close();
        return (Pais)listado.getFirst();
    }
}
```

Codigo de gestionLiga.altaJugador:

```
public void altaJugador(String nombre, String deporte, String ciudad, int edad, Pais pais)
{
    odb = ODBFactory.open("EQUIPOS.test");
    Jugadores jugador = new Jugadores(nombre, deporte, ciudad, edad, pais);
    odb.store(jugador);
    odb.close();
}
```

Codigo de la clase Pais

```
class Pais 
{
 private int id;
 private String nombre;

public Pais(){}

public Pais(int id, String nombre) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String toString()
{
    return this.nombre;
}
}
```

Codigo de la clase Jugadores

```
public class Jugadores 
{

private String nombre, deporte, ciudad;
private int edad;
private Pais pais;
public Jugadores(){} 

public Jugadores(String nombre, String deporte, String ciudad, int edad, Pais pais) 
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.deporte = deporte;
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.pais = pais;
}

public String getNombre() 
{
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) 
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDeporte() 
{
    return deporte;
}

public void setDeporte(String deporte) 
{
    this.deporte = deporte;
}

public String getCiudad() 
{
    return ciudad;
}

public void setCiudad(String ciudad) 
{
    this.ciudad = ciudad;
}

public int getEdad() 
{
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) 
{
    this.edad = edad;
}

public Pais getPais() {
    return pais;
}

public void setPais(Pais pais) {
    this.pais = pais;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "NOMBRE: " + nombre + " - DEPORTE: " + deporte + " - CIUDAD: " + ciudad + " - EDAD: " + edad + " - PAIS: " + pais;
}


}
```

Si introduzco 2 jugadores con el mismo nombre de pais, debería el segundo coger el objeto pais del primer jugador, sin embargo, entiendo que el código al hacer la query interpreta que el tamaño es 0 (no hay ninguno) y crea uno nuevo en la base de datos al entrar al IF

¡Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Con abrir la conexión al sacar el pais, no cerrarla al retornar, no abrirla (obvio ya que no se podría) al insertar un nuevo jugador y cerrarla tras el alta del nuevo jugador, se arregla el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con abrir la conexión al sacar el pais, no cerrarla al retornar, no abrirla (obvio ya que no se podría) al insertar un nuevo jugador y cerrarla tras el alta del nuevo jugador, se arregla el problema.

Comment: esto es un comentario o una respuesta?

Comment: es una respuesta, he conseguido dar con el problema